# Android, как сохранять данные без базы данных?

Tags: java, android

Только начала учить Android, пишу в `Android Studio`. Есть на уме идея для одной программы, но для этого мне надо научиться сохранять данные. Слышала, что использовать SqlLite нужно только при больших объемах памяти. Мне же, грубо говоря, нужно сохранять только имя пользователя и ещё какую-то общую информацию и выводить это в List. Как мне это сделать? Как правильно сохранять эти данные? В какой-то массив или отдельный файл?

Comment: Попробуй использовать SharedPrefrences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для сохранения данных вы можете использовать **SharedPreferences**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
```

Чтобы начать запись в файл настроек, вы должны вызвать метод `edit()` объекта SharedPreferences, 
который возвращает объект SharedPreferences.Editor.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

Объект SharedPreferences.Editor имеет несколько интуитивных методов, 
которые можно использовать для хранения новых пар ключ-значение в файле настроек. Например, вы можете использовать метод `putString()`,
 чтобы поместить пару ключ-значение со значением типа String

```
editor.putString("name", "Danil");
editor.putInt("age", 20);
```

Чтобы сохранить записи вы должны вызвать метод `commit()`.

```
editor.commit();
```

Чтение из объекта SharedPreferences гораздо проще. 
Всё, что вам нужно сделать, так это вызвать соответствующий метод `get*()`

```
String name = sharedPreferences.getString("name", "unknown");
int age = sharedPreferences.getInt("age", 0);
```

Comment: Спасибо. В каком файле сохраняются эти данные? Их вообще можно посмотреть?

Comment: @Біпач в Android Studio можно.

Comment: @Suvitruf, но где именно? Я не нашла файла  хотя бы с приблизительным названием "shared"

Comment: @Біпач в debug режиме с помощью adb https://stackoverflow.com/a/25585711/1991579

Comment: @Біпач Открываем папку data/data/имя_пакета/shared_prefs и видим там файл MainActivity.xml

Comment: Знаете, только что использовала выше написанный код и исполнила его при клике на кнопку. App на телефоне вылетает при клике и сыпятся ошибки в Logcat

Comment: @Біпач, задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: @Біпач стоит заметить, что предложенный вариант сохранят информацию в виде "ключ-значение", если нужно хранить больше информации то SharedPreferences не совсем тот инструмент. Ну и есть еще нюансы с областью видимости данного файла.

Comment: @ZigZag, тогда да, этот вариант мне не подходит. а как еще можно сохранять данные?

Comment: @Біпач добавил ответ в котором расписал основные варианты сохранения данных и подробно расписал вариант сохранения данных прямо в файл

Answer (score 1):

Основными вариантами хранения данных в Android, являются:

- сохранение пар "ключ-значение" для простых типов данных в общем файле
  настроек (SharedPreferences);
- использование баз данных под    управлением SQLite;
- сохранение произвольных файлов в файловой системе Android.

Так как мы выяснили, что в вашем случае SharedPreferences вам не подходят, а базой данных вы по каким-то причинам не хотите воспользоваться, то рассмотрим вариант сохранение произвольных файлов в файловой системе Android.

Для этого стоит воспользоваться объектом File который подходит для чтения или записи больших объемов данных в порядке от начала к концу без пропусков. Для того чтобы воспользоваться данным способом первоначально следует определиться где вы будете сохранять свой файл, во внутренней или внешней памяти.

Свойства внутренней памяти:

- всегда доступно.
- сохраненные здесь файлы по умолчанию доступны только вашему
  приложению.
- при удалении пользователем вашего приложения система Android удаляет
  из внутренней памяти все файлы этого приложения.

Свойства внешней памяти:

- доступно не всегда, потому что пользователь может в любое время
  подключать и отключать такие хранилища.
- такие хранилища доступны для чтения везде, поэтому вы не
  контролируете чтение сохраненных в них данных.
- при удалении пользователем вашего приложения система Android удаляет
  из внешних хранилищ файлы этого приложения, только если они
  сохраняются в директории с использованием getExternalFilesDir().

Рассмотрим вариант сохранения файла во внутренней памяти.

При сохранении файла во внутреннюю память вы можете получить соответствующую директорию в виде File, вызвав один из двух методов:

1. getFilesDir() - возвращает File, соответствующий внутренней
   директории приложения.
2. getCacheDir() - возвращает File, соответствующий внутренней
   директории файлов временной кэш-памяти приложения.
   Для создания файла в одной из этих директорий можно использовать конструктор File(), который передает элемент File, предоставляемый одним из вышеприведенных методов, с помощью которого указывается директория во внутренней памяти. Например:

   File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);

Кроме того, можно вызвать метод openFileOutput() для получения объекта FileOutputStream , производящего запись в файл во внутренней памяти. Вот пример записи текста в файл:

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```